# No Such Module 'SSZipArchive' using Carthage XCode 8.1

Tags: swift, carthage, ssziparchive

i want to add SSZipArchive to my project. I already run carthage update, add SSZipArchive.framework to embedded binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries
[image]

i also check Framework Search Paths and it's located right and have the file `ZipArchive.framework` and `ZipArchive.framework.dSYM` but i get `No Such Module 'SSZipArchive'`
what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have used `Carthage`, you need to add
`import ZipArchive` in the file where you want to use it instead of `import SSZipArchive`.

Source:[ViewController.swift in the demo project](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/blob/master/SwiftExample/SwiftExample/ViewController.swift)

```
#if UseCarthage
    import ZipArchive
#else
    import SSZipArchive
#endif
```

For the error:

> module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.1

rebuild your Carthage dependencies using the following command,

```
carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

Comment: error `module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.1`